# как поставить div внутрь image

Tags: html, css

Как сделать так что-бы div был на картинке, а не под ней ?

```
<div class="category-posts-columns-content clearfix" style="width: 165px; height: 100%; float: left; padding: 0.3em;">
    <h3 class="weekShowTitle" style="text-align:center"> 
        <span >Monday</span>
    </h3>
    <div id="post-vidshows-all" class="large-post post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail" >
        <img src="img/12.jpg" alt="12" style="cursor: pointer; z-index = 0;">
        <div style="z-index: 2; width:100%; height:auto;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: например можно поставить `div id="post-vidshows-all"` в стилях `position:relative` и нужному диву `position:absolute`

Comment: о да точно блин даже что-то из головы вышло большое спасибо !

Comment: @Grundy ответ стоило постить как ответ. даже если он короткий.

Comment: Поскольку ответ по сути есть, стоит переоткрыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Один из вариантов:
поставить `div id="post-vidshows-all"` в стилях `position:relative`
 и нужному диву `position:absolute`